# Matlab: Flipping specific rows in a column matrix

Tags: matlab

I would like to flip certain rows for a column matrix.
For example;

let Matrix A be:

```
1
2
**3**
**4**
**5**
**6**
7
8
9
10
```

I would just like to flip rows 3 to 6 such that matrix A becomes;

```
1
2
**6**
**5**
**4**
**3**
7
8
9
10
```

I have tried **flip** and **flipdim** command but it seems to flip the entire matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if `a=[1:10]'` as in your example, why not just :

```
 a(3:6)=flip(a(3:6))


>> a =

 1
 2
 6
 5
 4
 3
 7
 8
 9
10
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works. I applied a for loop for the same but this is much easier. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is no *efficient* way in doing this, i.e. there is no native function that just tells the interpreter, which values are flipped. So you will need to copy them

```
% create matrix size: (10x2)
Mat = repmat((1:11).',1,2);

% define section (index-wise)
sctIDX = [3   6
          10 11];
% now loop over the sections
for i = 1:size(sctIDX)
    % create logical vector for indexing rows
    lg = false(size(Mat,1),1);
    lg(sctIDX(i,1):sctIDX(i,2)) = true;

    % flip matrix section
    Mat(lg,:) = flip(Mat(lg,:),1); 
    % the second argument is the dimension: 1=rows, 2=columns
end
```

and the output is

```
1   1
2   2
6   6  %***
5   5  %***
4   4  %***
3   3  %***
7   7
8   8
9   9
11  11 %***
10  10 %***
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. It is helpful.

Comment: I understand that I am new and I may be making mistakes. I don't mind the downvotes on the question but if the person who downvotes takes the time to reason out why it was downvoted then maybe people like me and others who are new to posting questions here may have something to take back and learn from the downvotes. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I assume that this comment was meant to go below your original post, @Smalbro93 ;)